# Dynamic event of textbox

Tags: c#, events, textbox, tabs, notepad

How do you make an event dynamically? Like for example, I'm making a notepad with tab support for practice, and for every new tab, a text box is made dynamically. How can I make an event (TextChanged for example) for these text boxes?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think these events should do then?

Comment: Well, I need a MouseClick event to activate some tool tips, and also the TextChanged event to check if the current file has been modified or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `TextBox` object, assign the event on it and add to the tab control.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add("t1", "new 1");

    var tb = new TextBox();
    tb.TextChanged += (bs, be) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Text has been changed");
    };

    tabControl1.TabPages["t1"].Controls.Add(tb);
}
```

Comment: @Iceyoshi: Consider marking this answer as accepted if it solves your question. The checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

dynamicTextBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) => { your callback code goes here };